# Migrate lightning node daemon software

Tags: lightning-network

Is there a way to migrate from c-lightning to LND without having to close and reopen all channels?

Answer (score 3):

As the lightning network is a specified protocol and as both implementations are open source and spec compliant it should **theoretically** be possible to migrate from one implementation to another.

However **practically** spoken you will need a software tool that transforms all the internal data formats of `lnd` to the ones used in `c-lightning` without messing the nodes state. I am not aware of any tool that converts the internal data formats. That being said either you go out and create such a tool or you will have to install a new node (even with a new nodeid)

Comment: Connor said on a [github issue](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/1879) sometime back that c-lightning and LND uses a different seed formats and key derivation techniques which should impede the migration. I was unsure if these could be overcome by transforming internal data formats.

Comment: I just realized that the fact that lnd supports multiple channels between two peers which c-lightning from a software architectural design do and will not support. this migration also in practise will not work in every situation / in general.